# Why BigInteger.ONE not equals to new BigInteger("1") in java?

Tags: java, biginteger

While using BigInteger class in Java8, i wrote this piece of code

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("1")==BigInteger.ONE);
```

Ideally it should print true but its output is false. Why its output is false?

Comment: Why do you compare objects using the == operator? have you tried the equals check?

Comment: Because you are comparing objects with == operator. Use .equals instead.

Comment: exactly the same reason String s="name" is not equal to String s1=new String("name")

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` checks if the objects point the same reference, so that if `a = b` the condition `a == b`. It's recommended to only do this with primitive types.

To check if the objects' content is the same, use the function [`equals(Object otherObject)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). For example:

```
new BigInteger("1").equals(BigInteger.ONE);
```

This will return `true`, as both objects' content is the same. Using `==` will return `false` though, as each object have different references.

Another example would be this:

```
MyObject object1 = new MyObject(30);
MyObject object2 = object1; //this will make them have the same reference

// This prints true, as they have the same content.
System.out.println(object1.equals(object2));

// This will print true, as they point the same thing, because they have the same reference
System.out.println(object1 == object2);

// We can see they have the same reference because if we edit one's field, 
// the other's one will change too.
object1.number = 10;
System.out.println(object1.number); // prints 10
System.out.println(object2.number); // prints 10 too
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new BigInteger("1")==BigInteger.ONE
```

Can rewrite as

```
BigInteger bigint =new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger bigint2= BigInteger.ONE;
```

Now

```
System.out.println(bigint ==bigint2); //false
```

Because they points to different references.

== checks the reference.  Not the value inside them.

You can try using equals() method to check their equality.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using == instead of .equals(yourNumberToBeCompared)

You should do:

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("1").equals(BigInteger.ONE));
```